# python keyworded lambda function

Tags: python, object, lambda, typeerror, keyword

Here is a simple lambda express

```
var= lambda x: x*x
print(var(4))
```

simple I store the lambda object to a variable use the var to complete the math.

1. My question :

   How do I create function's that use  lambda's as keyworded arguments and uses them properly to preform certain tasks

In this code i get TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
    def test1(**kwargs):

        for fart in kwargs:

            print(fart)   #output is == key
            fart(4)   #fart(4)==TypeError

    test1(key=lambda x: x*x)
```

Comment: why is your element called fart? lol

Comment: I guess OP was annoyed by several hours trying to make that work. I would have used harsher variable names myself :)

Comment: I suspected he had to include the `r` after attempting to hold over 4GB of data within that variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because `kwargs` is a `dict`. In your case, this dict looks like this:

```
{'key': lambda x: x*x}
```

So when you iterate over the `dict`, you are really iterating over the keys, which in the case of `kwargs`, are strings (and strings are not callable).

If you really want to get at the lambda, then you should access the value within `kwargs` at that key:

```
for fart in kwargs:
    print(fart)
    print(kwargs[fart[](4))
```

Of course, there's an easier way to do this:

```
for fart, shart in kwargs.items():
    print(fart)
    print(shart(4))
```

Answer (score 1):

`kwargs` is a dictionary. Iterating on a dictionary gives you the key values.

Whn you iterate, just use `items()` or `values()` if you expect lambda functions for all keys:

```
for fart in kwargs:
    print(kwargs[fart](4))
```

or on values:

```
for fart in kwargs.values():
    print(fart(4))
```

More reasonably, what you need to call your lambda is to use the key `key`:

```
def test1(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs["key"](4))

test1(key=lambda x: x*x)
```

here it prints `16`